How does a change in potential energy of molecules lead to a change in kinetic energy?
When I think about other types of potential energy, it seems like there is a mechanical equilibrium, or a balance of forces. Then, when one force changes, movement occurs. For instance:

A brick resting on a surface: Gravity pulls the brick downward, and the surface pushes upward with an equal and opposite force.
Two magnets held apart by your hands: Your hands apply force to keep them apart, counteracting the attractive force between the magnets.
A stretched rubber band: Your hands apply a stretching force, while the rubber band exerts an opposing force as it "wants" to return to its original shape.

I don’t know the specific mechanism of why a rubber band “wants” to return to some shape, but I have some understanding about how it can create movement. I don’t have the same for potential energy in molecules.
Is there something similar here?

An atom in an excited state gives of electromagnetic radiation when it returns to the ground state. The radiation gets absorbed, exciting molecular vibrations. Now you have more kinetic energy (in the form of thermal energy) and less potential energy. Something similar happens in exothermic reactions. At the molecular level, it is less common that potential energy turns into concerted motion of many particles (what we call kinetic energy at the macroscopic scale), but it is possible to come up with these scenarios as well (they involve work rather than heat).

For atoms and molecules the potential energy typically come from electrostatic potential energy. As in, the potential of an electron (or nucleus) in response to the combined electric field from other electron and nuclei. Other electrons try push that particular electron while the nucleus try to attract it.
It's quite easy if you see the molecular Hamiltonian.


When a brick falls off the table, it releases energy. Ultimately, the brick and the surface get warm, i.e., molecules vibrate more. You can prove this to your satisfaction by repeatedly hitting a hard surface (e.g., a metal block), with a hammer. Feel it gradually warm.

When molecules are rearranged, e.g., $\ce{2H2 + O2 -> 2H2O}$, in some cases, they "snap" into place, vibrating the structure, releasing energy as heat (or light, as in a luminol reaction, or electric current, as in a cell).


Even simpler to understand is an electron being raised to a higher state, requiring energy, and then dropping back, releasing that energy, often as a photon of light. Hmm... a bit like that rubber band, if that's not too much of a stretch for that analogy.
